# Import tables to PostgreSQL from a local geopackage

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, postgresql, import

I'm trying to export each table from a local geopackage to a postgres database using `QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV3` but the tables are not written to the database.

```
gpkg_path = path/to/geopackage

# URI
uri = QgsDataSourceUri()
uri.setConnection(db_host, db_port, db_name, db_user, db_pass)

# LOAD THE GEOPACKAGE FILE
gpkg_layer = QgsVectorLayer(gpkg_path, 'geopackage', 'ogr')

# GET A LIST OF ALL THE TABLES IN THE GEOPACKAGE
tables = gpkg_layer.dataProvider().subLayers()
print(tables)

# LOOP THROUGH EACH TABLE AND EXPORT IT TO A DATABASE
for table in tables:
    # Get the name of the table
    table_name = table.split('!!::!!')[1]
    print(table_name)
    
    # CREATE A NEW QGSVECTORLAYER OBJECT FOR THIS TABLE
    gpkg_uri = f'{gpkg_path}|layername={table_name}'
    table_layer = QgsVectorLayer(gpkg_uri, table_name, 'ogr')
    print(table_layer)
 
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(table_layer)

    # SET THE OUTPUT TABLE
    uri.setDataSource(db_schema, table_name, 'geom')
    print(uri.uri())
    print()

    # EXPORT THE TABLE TO A DATABASE
    QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV3(
        table_layer,
        uri.uri(),
        'utf-8',
        QgsProject.instance().crs(),
        'PostgreSQL'
    )
    #  ADD TABLE AS LAYER
    db_new_table = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), table_name, 'postgres')
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(db_new_table)
```

Comment: You know of [Export to PostgreSQL](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/database.html#export-to-postgresql) right?

Comment: Yes. It depends on a variable with the name of the database connection in the QGIS browser. I would like to avoid it in my workflow.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the GDAL OGR command line tool `OGR2OGR` to copy all GPKG layers to PostgreSQL/PostGIS:

```
ogr2ogr -progress -append -f PostgreSQL PG:"host=<myhost> dbname=<mydb> active_schema=<myschema>" --config OGR_TRUNCATE YES --config PG_USE_COPY YES <myGPKG>
```

I'm using `-append` and `--config OGR_TRUNCATE YES` here, because I don't want to lose my database views when overwriting existing tables.

If you need Python, you can use the OGR2OGR Python bindings from here: https://svn.osgeo.org/gdal/trunk/gdal/swig/python/samples/ogr2ogr.py

```py
from osgeo import gdal
import ogr2ogr
pgConnection = 'PG:host=<myhost> dbname=<mydb> active_schema=<myschema>'
gpkgFile = '<myGPKG>'

# set GDAL config options
gdal.SetConfigOption("OGR_TRUNCATE", "YES")
gdal.SetConfigOption("PG_USE_COPY", "YES")

ogr2ogr.main(["","-append","-gt","65536","-preserve_fid","-f","PostgreSQL",pgConnection,gpkgFile])
```

Credit goes to the highly valued, tireless [Even Rouault](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/56122/even-rouault)! ...I kneel to the master